# Inconsistent loading of Glance in Watch OS 2

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

My Watch OS2 app has a glance, the top group is a static label, the bottom group is a WKInterfaceTable that gets populated via a call to HealthKit (workouts).  I also have an image as the bottom group's background.

The main part of the app features the same data loaded in a WKInterfaceTable.

I am testing on an Apple Watch and iPhone 5s.

The app itself works fine, no delay in loading the data at all.

However, the glance 9 times out of 10 only loads the top static label and not the bottom group (not even the background image)?  Every so often it will load correctly.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled but I can't figure it out.  Does the glance have anything to do with quality of network connection?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on Watch OS 1 where my labels were not updating correctly. I was first setting the label to empty strings, then set it to some dynamic text. For some cases, some labels were not setting the labels to empty strings.
Like yours, it was happening 9 out of 10 times.
I tried putting all the UI related stuff in the dispatch main thread, and it still had that issue.
In the end, I resolved it by first setting the labels to empty strings. Then, do a dispatch after of 0.1 secs to set the labels to the dynamic text.

Sample code snippet

```
[self.label1 setText:@""];
[self.label2 setText:@""];
[self.label3 setText:@""];
[self.label4 setText:@""];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    SampleViewModel *model = [accounts firstObject];
    if (model.currentText) {
        [self.label2 setText:[model formattedText]];
    } else {
        [self.label2 setText:@"Currently unavailable"];
        [self.label2 setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }

    [self.label3 setText:[model formattedText]];

    [self.label4 setText:model.accountNickname];
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did something similar in another app but I can't find it, could you add an implementation of the GCD to your answer?